# "from" is not valid at this position, expecting: EOF, ";"

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to increase John Smith salary by 10% and assume I don't know the emp_number for John Smith.

```
update m
    set m.mon_hourly_pay_rate = m.mon_hourly_pay_rate*1.1
from monthly_pay m
inner join Employee e
    on e.emp_number=m.emp_number
where e.emp_name = "John Smith";
```

Could anyone please help me. the word from have a red underline said "from" is not valid at this position, expecting: EOF, ";" but i google it and have not thing wrong with it

Comment: Which dbms are you using? `UPDATE ... FROM` is product specific functionality.

Comment: Please precise which DBMS are you using. Orcale? MySQL? ..

Comment: *"MySQLWorkbench"* is not a DBMS, this is a tool used to manage MySQL DBs

Comment: Check the syntax.

Comment: Syntax for MySQL is different in case of update. `update.. from` does not work in MySQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct. You need to use MySQL syntax as -

```
update monthly_pay m
       inner join Employee e
       on e.emp_number=m.emp_number
set m.mon_hourly_pay_rate = m.mon_hourly_pay_rate*1.1
where e.emp_name = "John Smith";
```